# Computer freezes for 2+ seconds, mouse still moves

Tags: linux, memory, freeze, intel-core-i7

I have this problem on my workstation. The computer would effectively freeze for 2-5 seconds for no apparent reason, then continue as normal. While frozen the mouse would still be movable, but only on one of screens in my multi-screen setup. What can be the likely cause.

System:

- CPU: i7-920
- Memory: 12G of Patriot DDR3, 6 modules
- OS: SLED 11, Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop, using Gnome
- Main board: Asus P6T
- Video: two Nvidia 9500GT connected to three displays

I am using memory at recommended settings of 8-8-8-1333. It has an XMP profile. Th CPU is a bit overclocked to 3.3 GHz, but my cooling more than allows for it. I ran the computer with all overclocks off and lower memory speed but the issue was still there.

Any ideas? Where should I start looking?

Comment: Check your hard drive.

Comment: Also make sure the drivers are okay.

Comment: As Shinrai mentioned, you want to look at your multi monitor setup.  It's very telling that the mouse only works on 1 screen.  Take a look at the drivers you have for each monitor and look for updates.  If that doesn't fix it look at your configuration, try a different type such as mirror or that one where both screens are the same (I think it's called twin).

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your workstation is mounting `/home` over nfs?  That can cause the exact symptoms you describe if your network connectivity gets interrupted or the nfs server goes down briefly.